# Recursive Class Objects and Member Variables in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, recursion, instance

Observe the following code:

```
class permcom:
  def __init__(self, INPUT_SET, IS_PERM, REPETITION):
    self.end_set = []
    self.input_set = INPUT_SET
    self.is_perm = IS_PERM
    self.repetition = REPETITION
  def helpfunc(self, seen, depth, current):
    if depth == 0:
      self.end_set.append(seen)
    else:
      for i in range(0, len(self.input_set)):
        if(self.repetition):
          seen.append(self.input_set[i])
          if(self.is_perm):
            self.helpfunc(seen, depth - 1, 0)
          else:
            self.helpfunc(seen, depth - 1, i)
          del seen[-1]

# return all permutations with repetition
def rapwr(INPUT_SET, subset_size):
  instance = permcom(INPUT_SET, True, True)
  A = []
  instance.helpfunc(A, subset_size, 0)
  return instance.end_set

A = [1,2,3]
B = rapwr(A, 2)
for i in range(0, len(B)):
  print B[i]
```

The output is the following:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

However, the intended output is this:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
```

I've spent way too much time looking at this code and, unfortunately, I still cannot figure out exactly what's wrong.  There must be something fundamental that I'm not understanding about how member variables work in Python, but I still don't quite understand what's going on here and why the code isn't working.  Can somebody explain this?

Comment: Could you explain in exhaustive detail what your code is supposedly  doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

What you need is list slicing `[:]`. Changing the statement

```
if depth == 0:
  self.end_set.append(seen)
```

to

```
if depth == 0:
  self.end_set.append(seen[:])
```

Gives the expected answer

**Long answer**

Try this sample code in a python interpreter

```
a = [1,2]
b = []
b.append(a)
a[0] = 3
print b
# output is [[3, 2]]
```

Now try this code

```
a = [1,2]
b = []
b.append(a[:])
a[0] = 3
print b
# output is [[1, 2]]
```

Why did this happen? In the first case when you appended `a` to the list `b`, it was not the *value* of `a` that was appended, it was a *reference/tag* to the `[1,2]` value. You can verify this by printing `id(b[0])` and `id(a)`. **Both will be the same value**. Hence when you modify any value in the `a` list, the value in the `b` list also changes.

Same is the case in your code. Since you are doing `del seen[-1]`, the corresponding value in `self.end_set` is also removed. You can confirm this by printing the value of `self.end_set` in the `depth == 0` block.

To avoid this you append a *clone* of one list to the other list. This is done by using the splicing syntax `[:]`. This creates a copy of the list from the start to the end of the list. You can learn more about slicing [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/).

PS: Try printing the `id()` of the two lists when you use slicing, **the values will be different**

Here is what I got

```
a = [1,2]
b = []
b.append(a)
print id(b[0])
#output is 43337352L
print id(a)
#output is 43337352L
b = []
b.append(a[:])
print id(b[0])
#output is 43337608L
```

Take a look at this python [memory model diagram](http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/) for a better understanding of the above

**Update: some advice**

1. Since `B` and `self.input_set` are both lists, prefer using the idiomatic `for i in B` and `for i in self.input_set`.
2. Make sure your function names are understandable. It might help you out someday. Generally if you are made to write a comment for a variable or function name, it is better to name the function/variable with a shortened version of the comment itself. So `rapwr` can be renamed to `return_all_permutations_with repetition`. Though the name is large, its easy to understand what it does without looking at the method body now.